# access the folder image docroot

Tags: image, jsf

I have a picture in glassfish docroot folder and display it but I need a relative path.

My code is as follows

```
 <h:graphicImage value="/#{detalle.path} />
```

And it produces the following result: 'localhost:8080/Gestion/image.png'

I need something like 'localhost:8080/image.png'

Note: Path is the image name.

How do I get this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h:graphicImage value>` implicitly prepends the context path in the URL. What you want is not possible with `<h:graphicImage>`. If you need to point to an image which is not part of the webapp, then just use plain HTML `<img>` instead.

```html
<img src="/#{detalle.path}" />
```